# searching items in a many2one field having the attribute widget="selection"

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I have created some groups of users who should not create new products while creating a purchase order. So as a solution, i made the product_id as a many2one field and in the xml side, i added widget="selection".
I have now a selection field without the possibility of creation of new products (which is good) but the problem is that i cannot search or filter these products.
Any ideas? 
(i Want to have this pop up window: 
[image]

Comment: Your question is not very clear, and seems not to be related to the posted image. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:
when i was using widget="selection", i had not the possibility to search more products because the field became a selection field. 
Instead, i used

```
 <field name="product_id"   options="{'no_quick_create': True, 'no_create_edit' : 
True}" />
```

Now, i have the "search more" option as shown in the picture below:
[image]

Comment: But that is not a solution to restrict the creation to _some_ groups but instead to all.

Comment: In fact i used a group_ids restricition:

Comment: I can't see it in your answer.